# How to concatenate strings as year month without using for loops

Tags: r

I am trying to create the strings `year,month` for several years (from 199701 to 200612). I can do it using for loops, is there a way to do this without using loops?

My goal:

```
#1997 01 to 2006 12
199701
199702
199703
199704
199705
199706
199707
199708
199709
199710
199711
199712
199801
.....
```

Comment: Why R U after such a non-loop solution?

Comment: I thought one of the "best practices" for R was to avoid loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
`dim<-`(outer(1997:2006,sprintf("%02d", 1:12),paste0),NULL)
```

Comment: Or, `sort(as.vector(outer(1997:2006, 1:12, sprintf, fmt = "%4i%02i")))`

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
paste0(rep(1997:2006, each=12), sprintf("%02d", 1:12))
```

Comment: Or, `sprintf("%4d%02d", rep(1997:2006, each=12), 1:12)`

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `expand.grid`

```
 do.call(paste, c(expand.grid(1997:2006, sprintf('%02d', 
           1:12)), sep='' ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

All answers posted so far include separate calls to `paste()` and `sprintf()` instead of *one* call to `sprintf()`.

The solution below is using the `CJ()` (*cross join*) function from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
CJ(1997:2006, 1:12)[, sprintf("%4i%02i", V1, V2)]
```

> ```
>   [1] "199701" "199702" "199703" "199704" "199705" "199706" "199707" "199708" "199709" "199710"
>  [11] "199711" "199712" "199801" "199802" "199803" "199804" "199805" "199806" "199807" "199808"
>  [21] "199809" "199810" "199811" "199812" "199901" "199902" "199903" "199904" "199905" ...
> ```